# Chars "<" and ">" don't work in cURL php

Tags: php, curl

I need to make a get request with this url:

```
http://example.com/save.asp?login=mylogin&password=mypass&str=<fio>name</fio><region>12</region><phone>08652545254</phone><work>test</wor>
```

I made this:

```
$url = "my url here";
$ch = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But it does not work. Seems the URL does not much in the end. So I cannot parse the name and phone on the server where I made the cURL request.

Comment: You need to [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) any query string parameter values with special characters, including `<` and `>`.

Comment: so I need to encode all my string? tryed this and it is not working my parameters are empyt

Comment: Where you are pulling the value for `str=` ... you need to wrap that value with `urlencode( $value_for_str );` Dont put urlencode around your entire `$url` variable. We cannot give you any exact example, because the code you show above just has `"my url here"` for whatever you are doing there.

Comment: got this. thank you very much guys. a made urlencode just the value for STR and it wors

Answer (score 1):

the fixed code:

```
$url="http://example.com/save.asp?login=mylogin&password=mypass&str=" . urlencode("<fio>name</fio><region>12</region><phone>08652545254</phone><work>test</wor>");
```